# Como corrigir os tipos do TypeScript no Service Worker?

Tags: typescript, service-worker, web-worker

Tenho um arquivo TypeScript que será usado no Service Worker, porém, por padrão, o escopo/contexto/`this` global e a variável `self` do arquivo sempre irá referenciar para o tipo Window, que não é o que acontece em tempo de execução:

```
// [...]

self.clients.matchAll()

// [...]
```

> Property 'clients' does not exist on type 'Window' .ts(2339)

Como configurar para que esse problema durante a compilação não ocorra e a IDE mostre as sugestões corretas ao digitar `self.<qualquer coisa>`?

Comment: Achei essa [discussão](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11781) no github talvez lhe ajude.

Answer (score -1):

Você precisa declarar o tipo da variável `this`, assim como você declara os tipos dos argumentos.

Por exemplo:

```
function onclickHandler(this: HTMLInputElement) {
    // como "this" é um input, aqui eu posso acessar a propriedade "value"
    console.log(this.value)
}
```

Repare que `this` não é o primeiro argumento da função, essa é apenas a sintaxe que o TS utiliza para declarar o tipo do `this`, na verdade essa função não está esperando argumento algum.

Como pode ser visto na seguinte código:

```
function recebeParametros(this: any, arg1: boolean, arg2: number, arg3: string[]) {
    console.log(arg1, arg2, arg3)
}

recebeParametros(
    true, 
    10, 
    ['a', 'b', 'c']
)
```

Eu nunca passo o valor de `this` para a função. Quando essa função é transcompilada para JS o `this` desaparece da declaração, ele só existe no TS para indicar o tipo de `this`.

Comment: Eu não me refiro a um valor recebido em alguma função, mas sim o `this` global, fora de funções, classes, objetos e outros escopos. Esse `this` no cliente é o objeto `window`, mas dentro de um Service Worker ele não é esse objeto e sim um do tipo `ServiceWorkerGlobalScope` (se não me engano). Se eu não configurar nada não tem como o TypeScript saber que esse arquivo específico é um Service Worker e então ele assume que é um Window, causando erro de compilação e na IDE